# error in receiving string in telnet

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, telnet

Hi i am trying automate my server, i send data using telnet,

code i have tried:

script.bat

```
Batch File (named Script.bat ):
     :: Open a Telnet window
START telnet 192.168.1.186 9760
cscript sendkeys.vbs
```

sendkeys.vbs

```
set OBJECT=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
For i=1 To 500
  If i=450 Then Exit For
OBJECT.SendKeys "00AC01{ENTER}" 
WScript.sleep 2000 

OBJECT.SendKeys "00AC01{ENTER}" 
WScript.sleep 2000 
Next
```

i cant receive the whole string `00AC01`,
help me on the this.

Comment: `Telnet Scripting Tool v.1.0 by Albert Yale` <--- free scriptable telnet.

Comment: [`plink`](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.63/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink) from the [PuTTY suite](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) is another free scriptable telnet. Please do **not** use `SendKeys` for automating telnet. *Ever.*

Comment: Unfortunately PuTTY uses the wrong character encoding for some devices (such as H3C Switches - I've had to use SendKeys to automate scripts for these switches), I posted my answer with the assumption that this was one such case. Use tools for telnet scripting wherever possible.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the SendKeys command in your vbscript is outputting to the window that you're calling the vbs file from, and not your telnet window. Something like this might work:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WScript.Sleep 2000
WshShell.SendKeys "telnet 192.168.1.186 9760"

OBJECT.SendKeys "00AC01{ENTER}" 
WScript.sleep 2000
```

Your batch file would only need to contain the call for the vbs file - therefore I suppose you wouldn't need the batch file.

Comment: i am just receiving a single character in my server 't'

Comment: With this script or your script?

Comment: your script..actually i running my own server,for that i want to automate and send commands ,i tried with netcat,but it dint help me. so i tried this way.

Comment: Also, why do you have your For loop exit at 450 with that if statement, as opposed to just changing the for loop to `For i=1 to 450`?

Comment: Take a look at the tools mentioned by foxidrive and Ansgar.